# método Auth::attempt laravel não está fazendo login

Tags: laravel

Estou tentando utilizar o método Auth::attempt para realizar login na minha api, mas sempre cai no else, mesmo quando possui no banco de dados a correspondência daquele email/senha. Onde posso configurar esse método Auth::atempt? Acredito que ele deve pegar o parâmetro padrão do laravel que é email/password, e como eu troquei para email/senha ele não encontra?

Minha função:

```
    function login(Request $request){

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'senha' => $request->senha])){
            return 'Autenticado com sucesso';
        }else{
        return response()->json([
        'error' => 'Nome de usuário ou senha incorretos',
        'code' => 401,], 401);
    }
}
```

Ela sempre cai no else..

Na minha função de registro é usado o Hash::make, isso impacta de alguma forma o Auth::atempt?

```
return User::create([
    'nome' => $data['nome'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'telefone' => $data['telefone'],
    'usuario_anjo' => $data['usuario_anjo'],
    'senha' => Hash::make($data['senha']),
]);
```

@Edit:

Fiz um teste trocando o Hash::make por bcrypty mas ainda cai no else...

Comment: Você mudou a tabela porque?

Answer (score -1):

Ao invés de gerar sua senha utilizando Hash:make, tente gerar utilizando a função bcrypt($data['senha']) e veja se funciona. Utilizando o método attempt do laravel você pode altenticar utilizando os campos que você deseja, não somente pelo email/password.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode definir um [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) no seu **App\User.php**.

```
/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->senha;
}
```

Esta resposta foi dada com base no caso abaixo por serem semelhantes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39382427/2116040